# Can't hit a breakpoint set in a newly added VB.NET WebForms page. How do I get the breakpoint to be hit?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2019

I have a VB.NET ASP.NET WebForms application which I'm running in VS2019, and I can set a breakpoint in an existing page's code, but if I try to set a breakpoint in a newly added page's code, I get this error message when I hover over it:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

How do I set a breakpoint in a newly added page such that I can actually hit the breakpoint? I already tried rebuilding the project containing my pages...

In case it matters, I'm running the web application through a local IIS instance pointed at my code, and attaching the debugger to the w3wp.exe process.

Comment: And now all of a sudden it works, weird...

Comment: Did you have optimizeCompilations set to true in the web.config? This has bitten me in the rear-end a few times.